# Spring Data JPA Query By Example with related entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I seem to be unable to add QueryByExample probes that match related entities.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ArtistEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<GenreEntity> genreList = new HashSet<>();
    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Data
public class GenreEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<ArtistEntity, Long> {
}
```

### When I try the following query, according to Hibernate's logs, my probe isn't running any conditions against the Genre

```
GenreEntity genreEntity = new GenreEntity();
genreEntity.setName("Heavy Metal");

ArtistEntity artistEntity = new ArtistEntity();

Set<GenreEntity> genreEntitySet = new HashSet<>();
genreEntitySet.add(genreEntity);

artistEntity.setGenreList(genreEntitySet);

Example<ArtistEntity> example = Example.of(artistEntity);
Pageable pagination = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
artistRepository.findAll(example, pagination);
```

---

I also tried looking on the Spring Data JPA documentation regarding QBE, but I didn't find anything specifically mentioning this limitation, which brought me to assume it's an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: the question is not clear, what kind of query that you are trying to perform ?, also i didn't notice any `GenreList` in `ArtistEntity` pojo

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh Sorry. Added the missing relationship to the example, also the ArtistEntity is the entity that I'm querying. I have a Repository on my example, and I'm doing a repository.findAll with an example, as is in the example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### Currently, you cannot do this with `Query By Example`.

The spring document states that this **only works with SingularAttribute.**

> Currently, only SingularAttribute properties can be used for property
> matching. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.running

You want to search by a property that is a `Set<GenreEntity> (genreList)`, which is a `PluralAttribute`. It is not possible to search by this field.

It will be ignored when building a query, as can be seen here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/convert/QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.java#L127

##### You can use `Specification`.

> Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl. https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

For this you need to extend from interface [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html):

```java
public interface ArtistRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<ArtistEntity>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ArtistEntity> {}
```

- And you also need to implement your custom `Specification<T>`.
- And then you can use `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`.

Comment: Thank you. I've came across mentions on Specification, but for some reason, I didn't find the post mentioning the limitation, so I was trying to work out with Example

Answer (score 0):

You may just use this library which supports nested fields and much more: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

It will let you run search queries such as:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**